# Similarity of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

If $S$ is a triangularizable matrix in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\rho{(S)}=1$(the spectral radius).
Can we get that $S$ is similar to 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}  B & 0 \\  0 & C \end{bmatrix}$$
 where spectrum of $B$ is on unit circle and spectrum of $C$ is into unit circle?

Answer (score 1):

No. The matrix

$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

has $\rho(S) = 1$ but it is not similar to a non-trivial block diagonal matrix because it is not diagonalizable.

Alternatively, consider

$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $$

which has $\rho(S) = 1$ but is not similar to a block diagonal matrix (trivial or not) for which the blocks have a spectrum that lie on the unit circle.

Comment: That's right, but if consider $B=S$ and $C=0$, then $S=B\oplus C$. Must $S$ be diagonalizable?  Can we cosider the Jordan form of this?

Comment: No, my comment is no true.

Comment: Well, I thought you meant that $S$ is similar to a non-trivial block matrix... (having blocks of positive size). Of course you can always take $B = S$ and $C = 0$ but you don't gain much from it and in any case, this also is not possible in the general case.

Comment: Ok. Is this form true for complex matrix?

Comment: @ela: No. The same examples work over the complex numbers as well.

Comment: In this case, the real matrix $S$ is with real spectrum, so  is $S$ similar to a block diagonal matrix that every matrix of diagonal is the jordan block?